# Which version of OpenGL to use?

Tags: c++, opengl, version

I currently run a machine that allows me to program in OpenGL 2.1. If I were to make a program, should I use the power of the current OpenGL versions like 3.x/4.x or use 2.1?

On a side question: How can I tell what's the highest version of OpenGL my computer can run?

On another side question: does ***only*** upgrading my video card allow me to program in upgraded versions of OpenGL?

Comment: This question appears to be a near-duplicate of this one: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/31505/what-opengl-versions-to-learn-and-or-use

Answer (score 36, accepted):

OpenGL versions (for AMD and NVIDIA GPUs) roughly correspond to levels of hardware. 2.x OpenGL versions are for DX9-level hardware. 3.x represents DX10-level, and 4.x represents DX11-class hardware. So the version you pick restricts you can run your code.

In general, any AMD or NVIDIA GPU you can actually buy new from a store will be 3.x or better (more than likely, 4.x). Even integrated GPUs, motherboard or CPU, from AMD are 3.x or better. I do some home development work on an HD 3300 motherboard GPU, and it works reasonably well.

Intel is a problem. Intel's OpenGL driver quality is pretty poor. Many old Intel machines can only support GL 1.4, which is pre-DX9 class functionality. They do support some higher-level extensions (shaders, but only vertex shaders, since they run them in software).

More recent Intel GPUs are a bit better, but their GL drivers are still rather buggy.

The above describes the situation for Windows. Linux is a bit fuzzier, because there are drivers from NVIDIA/AMD, and open-source community written drivers. The latter are generally not as good, but they are improving. These tend to be for 3.x-class hardware.

The MacOSX world is a bit different. Mac OSX Lion (10.7), recently released, adds support for OpenGL 3.2 (sadly, not 3.3, for some reason). Apple rigidly controls how OpenGL works on their platform, but hopefully they will be updating GL versions more frequently than they have been recently.

So on Macs, you really have two choices: 2.1 or 3.2. Note that Lion's 3.2 support only exposes *core* OpenGL functionality. See [this page](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Core_And_Compatibility_in_Contexts) for details on what that means.

You cannot tell what the highest version your particular computer is capable of. There is simply the version you get when you create a context. In general, unless you specifically ask for a version (and even then, usually not), you will get the highest version your hardware and drivers can handle.

Oh, and yes: the OpenGL version is controlled by your video card's capabilities (and installed drivers).

The following advise assumes that you're developing a serious application that you intend for others to use. This isn't for little demo apps or whatever.

In general, I would advise against explicitly restricting your code to 4.x. While 4.x adoption increases every day (there are 2 hardware generations from both NVIDIA and AMD with 4.x support, and a third likely will be out by years end from AMD. Also, AMD is starting to embed 4.x capable GPUs in their CPUs now), there is still a lot of 3.x hardware. 4.x doesn't buy you a whole lot, and you can easily add code paths to conditionally support 4.x features if they are available.

Comment: With at least AMD and nVidia, OpenGL version is determined by driver version.  Older cards may be less accelerated, but I think they'll still run 4.1 code.  Or do you have experience otherwise?

Comment: @Ben Voigt: I've never seen a DX9-level card advertise OpenGL 3.x. I've never seen a DX10-level card advertise OpenGL 4.x. None of my DX10 cards expose 4.x because they can't handle it, regardless of the driver version (and yes, I'm up to date). And neither AMD nor NVIDIA wants to lie to their users by promising features and then running them in software. The only time I've seen this violated is if you use a special software driver mode from NVIDIA, and that requires going to NVIDIA's control panel to activate it.

Comment: Ah, nevermind, I was thinking Radeon HD 5xxx was DX10.1 and 6xxx was DX11.  And 5xxx definitely supports OpenGL 4.x.  But now I see that is a DX11 class card, completely consistent with what you said.

Comment: Now that it's 2013, roughly 90% of Steam users can run OpenGl 3.0, whereas *significantly* fewer users can run DX9 due to OS limitations.  Reference: http://www.gdcvault.com/play/1017850/ (jump to minute 14 for a useful graph!)

Answer (score 4):

In order to use OpenGL 3.x you need a card that supports DirectX10 and proper drivers that have support for it. 
The advantage in opposite to DirectX is, that you can also use OpenGL3 and 4 on WindowsXP. No need for 7 or Vista. 
Which version you should use depends on your audience. If your audience are gamers, go ahead, use 3. Won't do 4 exclusive yet. DX11 are still rare. 
For a first look on how Gamers use their computers and what hardware they have, steam is a good source:

http://store.steampowered.com/hwsurvey

You can determine the version by running:

```
glGetString(GL_VERSION);
```

A good OpenGL3 Tutorial:

http://arcsynthesis.org/gltut/

The OpenGL 3.3 SDK Reference:

http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man3/

Hope this helps a bit :).

Comment: I guess I'll most likely use 2.1 for now to support as many video cards as possible, and move on to 3.x in the future. :)

Answer (score 3):

Lots of embedded Intel graphics are limited to 1.4 or 1.5.

Mac OSX is stuck on 2.1 I hear.

All Radeon and GeForce cards can do 3+ (may need a driver update).

And you can program with any version, but if your hardware doesn't support it, you'll end up testing under a software renderer (slow!).

Comment: On Linux Intel DRI2/DRM drivers do support OpenGL 2.1 plus some extensions.

Comment: Actually, if the hardware doesn't support a version, but you try to use it anyway, then you won't be able to get those function pointers. You won't get software rendering; you'll get a bad function pointer/crash. Or you'll pass an enumerator to a function that can't handle it, and you'll get a GL_INVALID_ENUM error.

Comment: @datenwolf: For which generation of GMA?

Comment: @Nicol: If you use a hardware accelerated context, then yes, newer functions may just fail.  But there are software renderers available, if you need to test a codepath without hardware.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas: The reported OpenGL version is 2.1 and the extension string says the same.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: Output of glxinfo on my notebook (Intel(R) GM45 Express Chipset): http://pastebin.com/isybhCnB

Answer (score 0):

> On a side question: How can I tell what's the highest version of OpenGL my computer can run?

I answer for the above question.
I come across to the tool below, it's really complete in itself and let me see all OpenGL version that my system currently support (from 1.0 up to what it actually support). As well for extensions available for my system to use. Not only for ARB though, it ranges from NV, ATI, OES, etc.

http://www.realtech-vr.com/glview/download.html

Comment: [GLEW](http://glew.sourceforge.net/) contains `visualinfo` and `glewinfo` which give you the same information in txt file. So there's no need to go to some ugly website that doesn't align page content properly...