# Which version of OpenGL should I learn?

Tags: opengl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which version of OpenGL to use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6823371/which-version-of-opengl-to-use)

I have been wanting to learn a 3d graphics language for some time now and I have finally decided to learn OpenGL. 
However, I work on a Mac and officially this highest version of OpenGL for mac is 2.1 but it can support 3.3 unofficially through tests that I have done.

I would like to develop applications that would work on multiple platforms but what version would be the best to learn?

Answer (score 11):

A good compromise between portability and still learning the "modern OpenGL way", is roughly "the OpenGL ES 2.0 subset of OpenGL 2.1". That gives you portability to

- OSX, as you mention
- Windows, obviously
- Linux with open source drivers (for higher OpenGL versions and better performance you need the proprietary drives which you might prefer anyway, but some people like to avoid those)
- Smartphone platforms like iOS and Android.

OpenGL 1.x is even more portable (e.g. older iOS and Android releases support only OpenGL ES 1.x) but the classical fixed-function programming model is somewhat different than the modern one based on buffer objects and shaders, and use of immediate mode easily leads to performance issues when rendering lots of vertices. So probably not worth it, IMHO.

Comment: Yet the best answer among the a bit narrow-minded "OpenGL 2.1 is deprecated!"-answer and the ridiculous idea of learning WebGL or GLES on desktop.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation would be to learn *no less* than version 3.2. If 3.3 is supported (even unofficially), go for that.

OpenGL 3.3 is already rather "last generation" than "bleeding edge". You have to search hard to find a card that does *not* support OpenGL 3.3, and you get 4.x capable cards in the $30 range.

Under version 2.x, you must go through a lot of pain to ensure that even the most basic functionality that you use every day is available, and you end up writing two or three code paths depending on what extension you must use and on what some limit is.
Under version 3.3, most features that you want to use every day are core (guaranteed standard), and most limits have a guaranteed minimum value that is enough for most things anyway. The features that are not core in 3.3 are few (and you won't die if you don't have them), and you can pretty much just plug them in optionally if they're there, and forget about them if they aren't.

There is a huge change in paradigms between 2.1 and 3.3 (which you will have to re-learn later if you start with 2.x first!), and there are notable changes in GLSL between 3.1 and 3.2 which make writing shader code that works for both an ordeal, or impossible.
Upwards of version 3.2, everything is smooth. New features are available or they aren't... use them or don't... but you can in principle write one piece of code to run on all versions.

Answer (score -1):

If your goal is maximum interoperability, I would rather take a look at [WebGL](http://www.khronos.org/webgl/), or it's close relative, [OpenGL ES](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/). The concepts of OpenGL ES (at least in the 2.0 version) are quite close to those of OpenGL 4 (buffer-based data transfer, universal shaders etc.).

I think that by learning 2.1 you would learn some outdated concepts you will soon have to re-learn, like the direct mode, or rather the whole [fixed-function pipeline](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Fixed_Function_Pipeline) which was pruned in later versions.

You can safely start learning the 3.x too, as you will learn the current concepts and features. Do not worry about the "officially supported" version.

Comment: I believe it is wrong to guide someone towards WebGL. WebGL is to access native GPU capabilities on the web, and openGL is for accessing native GPU capabilities as a native application. Also, WebGL has its own portability problems with only Chrome (and Opera) supporting it fully (as of now) as per http://caniuse.com/webgl.